# Is Dajjal natural evil?

Tags: dajjal

Is Dajjal natural evil? Did Allah created him evil to test mankind or his like satan chose to become evil by his own will?

Comment: http://www.inter-islam.org/faith/dajjal.htm

Comment: You might want to see [this answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37733/is-attributing-evil-to-satan-heresy/37740#37740). Allah doesn't create the evil in the sense that he creates sun, human, water, vegetables, fire, people, etc. . He creates people, but also **commands** them to do good. Then they choose to do become prophets or someone like dajjal—freely

Comment: @Thaqalain Wrong. Allah wrote down the deeds of every person before they were born.

Answer (score 1):

He  is often depicted as an embodiment of evil and falsehood. According to Islamic tradition, Dajjal is a false messiah who will emerge before the end of time and will deceive people with his supernatural powers and false claims.

While Dajjal is not considered a "natural evil" in the traditional sense, his actions and influence are believed to be a manifestation of evil in the world. Islamic scholars generally understand evil to be a combination of moral, spiritual, and natural factors, and consider the existence of evil to be a test and a trial for humanity.

In Islamic belief, Allah (God) is ultimately responsible for everything that happens in the world, including the existence of evil. However, the presence of evil is also seen as a result of human free will, and the choices that people make to either follow the path of righteousness or to succumb to temptation and sin.

In summary, while Dajjal is not considered a natural evil, his actions and influence are seen as a manifestation of evil in the world, and his emergence is believed to be a sign of the end times in Islamic eschatology.

To find out more about this please follow the link:
https://www.islamiqate.com/1299/could-muslims-follow-dajjal-having-warned-prior-existence