# Did Allah create evil?

Tags: allah

Like in the title I said did Allah create evil or it's just   independent creation that it created own it's own or bys us or just to balance the good ?

Comment: see [this answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37733/is-attributing-evil-to-satan-heresy/37740#37740)

Answer (score 4):

The below verses answer this question, without any need for elaboration:

> Say, "Who is Lord of the heavens and earth?" Say, " Allah." Say, "Have
>   you then taken besides Him allies not possessing [even] for themselves
>   any benefit or any harm?" Say, "Is the blind equivalent to the seeing?
>   Or is darkness equivalent to light? Or have they attributed to Allah
>   partners who created like His creation so that the creation [of each]
>   seemed similar to them?" Say, " **Allah is the Creator of all things**,
>   and He is the One, the Prevailing. (13:16)
>
> **Allah is the Creator of all things**, and He is, over all things,
>   Disposer of affairs. (39:62)
>
> [He is] Originator of the heavens and the earth. How could He have a
>   son when He does not have a companion and **He created all things**? And
>   He is, of all things, Knowing. That is Allah , your Lord; there is no
>   deity except Him, **the Creator of all things**, so worship Him. And He is
>   Disposer of all things. (101 - 102) Surat Al An'aam

Comment: TLDR; Yes he did.

Answer (score 0):

ALLAH (SWT) says in Quran that He is the one who created everything. Everything in this world is a test for us. So he can judge who is more in righteous among us. 
So yes ALLAH (SWT) did made Evil.

Answer (score -1):

Allah created the good and the bad to test his creation and test their faith. Allah created trials and tribulations to not only test but as a means of mercy to those who patient and faithful.

Allah also created provisions for all of us. Allah is all just, all wise and it is us who are finite in our wisdom. There is no evil except for their is its cure.

This is why this worldly life is but a short journey and the hereafter is where none of these worldy concerns (worry, sadness, jelousy, envy, or any negative emotions exist). For those who are admitted into Jannah by being sincere will attain this reward. Whilst those who were evil have a worse ending.

My Allah make us from the people of Jannah.