# What is Allah (swt), neither good nor evil?

Tags: allah

What is Allah (swt), neither good nor evil? Just neutral? Because Allah (swt) created good and evil, so he can't be bound by those attributes. If he is bound by his own creation or something like that then he is not omnipotent. So is he neutral or above them ?

Please forgive me if I said something wrong or haram, let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37733/is-attributing-evil-to-satan-heresy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Allah knows what is [presently] before them and what will be after them, but they do not encompass it in knowledge. 20:110**

Whatever we think of Allah, and however we imagine Him is incomplete. That, I would say, includes statements like **Because Allah created good and evil, so he can't be bound by those attributes. If he is bound by his own creation or something like that then he is not omnipotent.** Because the statement itself make assertions. (However, the assertion that **"Whatever we think of Allah, and however we imagine Him is incomplete."** is not in that category, because it is simply admitting that we cannot know.)

We know Allah by way of His attributes given to us in Quran. That He is All Merciful, He is All Knowing, that He is All Seeing, ... I would suggest you to find a good book on the Names of Allah. (I have an excellent source in Turkish, I do not know what is available in English.) (You will hear that Allah has 99 names, which is mentioned in a reliable hadith. That, of course, does not mean that Allah is bounded by those 99 attributes; just that [possibly], 99 of them are mentioned in Quran.)

Whoever makes assertions which is not directly backed up by Quran and hadith is armchair-philosophizing. It is going to be wrong, and the above ayah is a warning against that.

Answer (score 2):

An entity whose mercy encompasses all things (Quran **7:156**) cannot be identified as "not good".

An entity who orders Its creation to be good and just (Quran **16:90**) can not be identified as "not good" or "neutral".

Allah is just (Quran **53:31**, **95:8**).

Considering the neutrality between "good vs. evil", a neutral entity can be just, in that sense. However, that neutral entity can't order good. Which leaves us with the fact that Allah is good.

**EDIT:** "he can't be bound by those attributes. If he is bound by his own creation or something like that then he is not omnipotent."

Your argument is not correct. Allah shares some attributes with Its creation to a degree. Some examples: To exist; we exist, Allah exists too. To be alive; we are alive (before our deaths), Allah is alive too. To speak; we speak, Allah speaks too (in different ways). To make things; we make things (cars, buildings, etc.), Allah makes things too (universes, planets, stars, angels, humans, trees, ... the difference being without needing a tool or material) and many more.

Answer (score 2):

there is an ayat in which allah says that bad things are from people themselves, and good things are from allah, 4:79:

"Sahih International" translation:

(78:) Wherever you may be, death will overtake you, even if you should be within towers of lofty construction. But if good comes to them, they say, "This is from Allah "; and if evil befalls them, they say, "This is from you." Say, "All [things] are from Allah ." So what is [the matter] with those people that they can hardly understand any statement? (79:) What comes to you of good is from Allah, but what comes to you of evil, [O man], is from yourself. And We have sent you, [O Muhammad], to the people as a messenger, and sufficient is Allah as Witness.

you can read at https://quran.com/4/77-80 .

Comment: This answer should address the doctrine that evil is part of creation, and that all of creation is from Allah.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement that Allah created evil is not correct.  Misguided people perform 'evil' actions, or say 'evil' statements.  They do evil when they are not Allah conscious when they conduct themselves.  The constant temptations and whispers by Sheythan does not help.  They need to be Allah conscious as they conduct themselves throughout the day.  This is known as 'Taqwa' and it is emphasized repeatedly throughout the Quran.  Just one sample:

Quran: 59.18 
Yā 'Ayyuhā Al-Ladhīna 'Āmanū ***Attaqū Allaha*** Wa Ltanžur Nafsun Mā Qaddamat Lighadin ۖ ***Wa Attaqū Allaha*** ۚ 'Inna Allāha Khabīrun Bimā Ta`malūna

O ye who believe! **Fear God**, and let every soul look to what (provision) He has sent forth for the morrow. Yea, ***fear God***: for God is well-acquainted with (all) that ye do.

ي‍‍َ‍ا‌أَيُّهَا‌ ‌الَّذ‍ِ‍ي‍‍نَ ‌آمَنُو‌ا‌ ‌**اتَّ‍‍قُ‍‍و‌ا‌ ‌اللَّ‍‍هَ** ‌وَلْتَ‍‌‍نْ‍‍‍‍ظُ‍‍رْ‌ نَفْسٌ‌ مَا‌ قَ‍‍دَّمَتْ لِ‍‍غَ‍‍د‌ٍ‌ ‌**وَ‌اتَّ‍‍قُ‍‍و‌ا‌ ۖ ‌اللَّ‍‍هَ** ‌إِنَّ ۚ ‌اللَّ‍‍هَ خَ‍‍ب‍‍ِ‍ي‍‍ر‌ٌ‌ بِمَا‌ تَعْمَلُونَ

Quran 59:19
Wa Lā ***Takūnū*** Kālladhīna Nasū Allaha Fa'ansāhum 'Anfusahum ۚ 'Ūlā'ika Humu Al-Fāsiqūna

And be ye not like those who **forgot God**; and He made them forget their own souls! Such are the rebellious transgressors!

وَلاَ‌ **تَكُونُو‌ا**‌ كَالَّذ‍ِ‍ي‍‍نَ نَسُو‌ا‌ ‌اللَّ‍‍هَ فَأَ‌نْ‍‍سَاهُمْ ‌أَ‌نْ‍‍فُسَهُمْ ۚ ‌أ‍ُ‍‌وْل‍‍َ‍ائِكَ هُمُ ‌الْفَاسِ‍‍قُ‍‍ونَ

The practice of the 5 daily salat, zekat (charity), and sawm (fasting) help to enforce taqwa.

Allah is the most beneficent (Al Rahman), the most merciful (Al Raheem), the most good, and the source of goodness.

Another way to define evil:

There is no real such thing as darkness.  It is simply the absence of photons (electromagnetic waves/particles) of visible wavelength.  Allah created light.  Darkness is the absence of light.

There is no real such thing as cold.  It is simply the absence of heat (thermal energy of photons in the infrared wavelengths emitted by molecules in motion).  Allah created heat.  Cold is the absence of heat.

There is no real such thing as silence.  It is simply the absence of sound (mechanical vibrations in air and other matter).  Allah created sound.  Silence is the absence of sound.

So, there is no real such thing as 'evil'.  It is simply the possible resulting conduct of people who are not practicing taqwa.  Allah created good. Evil is the absence of good.